# How can I elegantly handle server error where the database is unavailable in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, error-handling

I have an ASP.NET web application. I've set up IIS 8.5 to handle various HTTP error responses using static HTML error page e.g.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      ...
      <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="httpErrors\custom" path="500.htm" responseMode="File" />
    ...
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```

I've also set my application to delegate exception handling to IIS because I want to be sure any exceptions which cause the application to fail are still handled elegantly. Therefore I've set my web.config as:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/CustomError.aspx" mode="On" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

CustomError.aspx just looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = false;
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to tell my application to defer to IIS for error handling.

If I now simulate a server error by throwing an exception I see my request is redirected to /CustomError.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/path/to/fracture.aspx. In this case the application's customErrors setting has kicked in presumably because the exception has been thrown in ASP.NET. However, what I see is my 500.htm page configured in httpErrors (see above).

If I simulate a server error a different way by simply setting `Response.StatusCode = 500;` then this time I am not redirected but I still see the contents of my 500.htm error page. Presumably this time IIS is handling the server error without the application's involvement.

Both these things are **good** :)

*However*, now I want to see what happens if my database goes down. To simulate this I change my connection string to point to a database which doesn't exist. Which of the above scenarios do you think I observe? Neither! What I actually see is a very ugly:

> **Server Error in '/template' Application.**
>
> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

I can see in the browser address bar that I've been redirected to CustomError.aspx so the application has handled the error as expected. You can see from the code of CustomError.aspx above that it makes no database calls. In fact it barely does anything. So why am I not seeing my nice friendly error page? I can even see from monitoring the request that it's still a 500 status code.

A lot of detail I know, but I'm really keen to find a standard and reliable approach to error handling that never exposes any ugly ASP.NET messages.

Comment: then you shouldn't do anything that "might" cause exception inside your error page/handler. Would be ideal if it is just a .html file.

Comment: That's a fair point. But then I don't have the option of delegating the error handling to IIS. Which is OK I guess but it means I can't benefit from serving multilingual static errors (although that's another story - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178743/how-can-i-achieve-multi-lingual-server-errors-in-an-asp-net-application)

Comment: you can setup a custom error page in IIS which will do both the error logging in the IIS log and show a friendly page

Comment: But the customErrors section requires me to point at a specific file so I can't use the prefixLanguageFilePath functionality that IIS offers when it handles errors direct?

Comment: can you whack a sample cut down .sln onto GitHub temporarily ? it will help for people providing answers